# Change type of value in collection using update

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am looking for a way, how to update multiple documents in MongoDB. I want to modify similar structure like this one:

```
{[
   "_id": 'mongo_id',
   "name": "Name"
]}
```

to the structure like this, basically just change string attribute to object attribute with string property :

```
{
   "_id": 'mongo_id',
   "name": {
       "type_1": "Name",
       "type_2": "" 
    }
}
```

Is there a way how to do it in single mongo query or I have to create some kind of worker for example in node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the best solution is create little worker to get all documents and update them in collection. I used node.js and mongodb npm package to create worker similar to this one:

```
var mongo = requiere('mongodb');

mongo.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, function(err, database) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    db = database;

    db.collection('<collectionName>').find({}).toArray(function(err, array) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return process.exit(1);
        }
        console.log('length:', array.length);
        var promises = [];
        array.forEach(item => {
            promises.push(db.collection('<collectionName>').update(
               {
                  _id: item._id
               }, 
               {
                 '$set': { 
                    'name': {
                       'type_1': item.name,
                       'type_2': '',
                     } 
                  }
            }))
        });

        return Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
            console.log('Done');
            return process.exit(0);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log('err:', err);
            return process.exit(1);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any schemas involved to put constrains on your collections or if you have and name is defined as `mixed` type (from mongoose types as an example) then you can do whatever you want to any of the properties other than `_id`.

for example this update will change `name` to the object you want:

```
db.getCollection('<collectionName>').update({
  _id: "mongo_id")
}, {
name: {
  "type_1": "Name",
  "type_2": ""
}
})
```

Comment: I am looking for way, how to do it in all documents in collection. I already created small cron that transform all documents and update database. I just wonder if there is way how to do it dynamically for collection only in mongoDB.